# Is there C# compiler for Mac OS X?

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, compiler-construction

I want to build my ASP.NET C# Desktop Application on Mac OS and output must be application running on Mac OS.How can I do that?Is there any compiler?

Comment: "ASP.NET" and "Desktop Application" don't belong in the same sentence.  ASP.NET is for web applications.  Which is it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at the Mono Project.

http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I installed Mono and MonoDevelop IDE.But the builds result is an EXE file which is suitable for Windows OS. I need MAC OS application. I can drive the EXE file in MonoDevelop run item but is not executable out of MonoDevelop.

Comment: EXE file of an .Net app is not tied to Windows; rather, it's tied to a CIL runtime, of which Mono is one. You just need to tell OS X to use Mono to run the EXE file, see http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2010/01/24/creating_mac_app_bundle_for_gtk_app for example.

Comment: 3 years later and I stumble across this. I'm glad I did!